# Sum if 1 criteria is text and 2 criteria is color in google sheet

Tags: excel-formula

I have used the script below:

```
function sumColoredCells(sumRange,colorRef) {
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet();
  var formula = activeRange.getFormula();

  var rangeA1Notation = formula.match(/\((.*)\,/).pop();
  var range = activeSheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation);
  var bg = range.getBackgrounds();
  var values = range.getValues();

  var colorCellA1Notation = formula.match(/\,(.*)\)/).pop();
  var colorCell = activeSheet.getRange(colorCellA1Notation);
  var color = colorCell.getBackground();

  var total = 0;

  for(var i=0;i<bg.length;i++)
    for(var j=0;j<bg[0].length;j++)
      if( bg[i][j] == color )
        total=total+(values[i][j]*1);
  return total;
}
```

and then used the formula

```
=IF(A2:A10,"A",sumColoredCells(B2:B10,D3))
```

In A Column there are is text value and B column there are yellow color with number value. I want the yellow color with number which correspond to A results a total sum in cell D2.

Check the screenshot below.
[image: Ref]

Comment: I think i have not nested the function effectively!

Comment: So, the issue is resolved ?

Comment: Don't know about the function but the IF formula is clearly wrong, there's no logical test as the first criteria of the function, there's only a cell reference.

Comment: What formula should i use in combination of sumColoredCells to add text criteria?

Comment: I do believe that you'll need to either change the sumColoredCells or just filter the data, the formula that you would normally need would be SUMIF not IF, and neither of those will achieve what you need.

Comment: You'd be better off either writing the whole thing into the `sumColoredCells` function, or writing a function to return the cell colour and looking at `SUMPRODUCT` and Array Formulae.